# F# WPF Attributes have been ignored in this construct

Tags: wpf, f#, sta

So. I was following along some tutorials on using WPF with F# [blog here](http://jyliao.blogspot.com/2007/10/learning-wpf.html).
I am working with the second one.

Since I am trying to learn F# WPF for larger more enterprise applications, it doesn't make much sense for me to use a bunch of F# script files. So I tried to convert it a regular .fs file as a type that I could create an instance of in a main method elsewhere.

```
namespace wpf
   module File1 =

       open System
       open System.Windows
       open System.Windows.Input
       type handleEvent ()=
           (* From Chap 1 - HandleAnEvent.cs *)
           let WindowOnMouseDown sender (args:MouseButtonEventArgs) =
              let win = unbox<Window> sender
              let str = String.Format("Window clicked with {0} button at point ({1})",args.ChangedButton,args.GetPosition(win))
              MessageBox.Show(str)|>ignore

           let win = new Window()
           [<STAThread()>]
           do 
               win.Title <- "Handle an Event"
               win.add_MouseDown(new MouseButtonEventHandler(WindowOnMouseDown))

               let app =  new Application() in
                app.Run(win) |> ignore
```

It looked like a pretty faithful recreation to me. I was able to take care of all that #r stuff by adding assembly references to the project. But now instead of a red error, I am getting a blue warning all over my do block that says:

```
Attributes have been ignored in this construct
```

When I googled that warning I came up empty handed so I thought I would get help here.
I need that attribute to be able to properly run WPF I know it has something to do with the threads and without it, I will get this serious exception:

```
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this
```

So what is my work around to apply the STA thread attribute to what is needed?
Also, why is this construct invalid for STA in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `[<STAThread>]` must go on a method - something like

```
[<STAThread()>]
let main() = 
   win.Title <- "Handle an Event"
   win.add_MouseDown(new MouseButtonEventHandler(WindowOnMouseDown))
   let app =  new Application() in
   app.Run(win) |> ignore
```

I anticipate that in your case it is not required to go in this file - you should just ensure that the topmost function (`main` or similar) is marked with STAThread.

Comment: Oh weird, I did not realize that was the case, The example code I was looking at had it surrounding a do block in a .fsx.

Comment: Attaching the attribute to a top-level `do` block in a module would be fine too - the difference is that in your code, you are attaching it to a local `do` block inside a type (and that does not work)